# WebStorm Code Style Templates - TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm

Currently based on the TypeScript code style settings in my WebStorm IDE, the Angular `@Component` decorator code is is being formatted as follows:

```
@Component({
               selector: 'my-component',
               templateUrl: 'my.component.html',
               styleUrls: ['my.component.scss']
           })
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
```

What I would like is that it is formatted like this when performing an auto format:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: 'my.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['my.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
```

However I'm failing to find the correct settings. I have the following settings on the `Tabs and Indents` tab under `Editor > Code Style > Typescript` in WebStorm Settings:

[image]

Comment: This is "Wrapping and Braces", no?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The key was to ensure "Method call arguments > Align when multiline" on the "Wrapping and Braces" tab is unchecked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @jonrsharpe for pointing me in the right direction, I've managed to figure this out...

1. In WebStorm go to **File** > **Settings**, then **Editor** > **Code Style** > **Typescript**
2. Click on the **Wrapping and Braces** tab
3. Ensure the **Method call arguments** > **Align when multiline checkbox** is unchecked:

[image]